# Can a developer claim credit / ownership of my software licensed under the MIT License?

Tags: open-source-software

A user forked a repository made by me that is licensed by the MIT License. He made a few changes to the code and added the following line to the README.md

```
Made by [HisName]! Contact me at [HisName]#0675
```

Is that legal?

Comment: To clarify, your contention is that the code base, with this individual's changes, is your code and not his?

Comment: Is the license statement itself, including the name of the copyright holder, still there?

Answer (score 2):

Providing your copyright notice (if any) and the MIT license has been included, yes.

Answer (score 1):

From the MIT license page at:

[MIT License Page](https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT)

The following text appears:

> Copyright YEAR COPYRIGHT HOLDER
>
> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining
> a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the
> "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including
> without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish,
> distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to
> permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to
> the following conditions:
>
> **The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be**
> **included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.**

As long as the conditions spelled out in the final sentence are followed, yes "HisName" can do whatever he wants.

If you wanted to protect against this, you should have chosen a different license.  You cannot take back this previously licensed code but any future releases or updates can use a different license.

Comment: But the license reads ' free to modify without restriction' so couldn't @Will just make a copy of the code and remove the contact information for the version that Will distributes?

Comment: No, the ONE condition is that the copyright notice shall be included.  That's the ORIGINAL copyright notice.